# (streamlit) Error “selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException” although app works fine locally

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, streamlit

I’ve got **[this streamlit app](https://multicityjourneys.streamlit.app/)** I can run just fine locally but I get an error message seemingly pertaining to `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException`. Here’s the snapshot of the error message, would be great if someone could help solve what’s going wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service...
```

...implies that as you are using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) the [WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver) class expects a *`Service`* type of argument as an argument.

---

### Solution

You need to pass the *`ChromeDriverManager().install()`* as an argument of `Service` type as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```